# Live application migration between two different versions of Erlang VMs

Tags: erlang

I have Erlang application running on R13 version of Erlang VM.
I want to upgrade VM to R14 without stopping the application.
How cay I do live migration of the application between
different versions of Erlang VM?

Answer (score 4):

You need two things:

a) Lots and lots of planning.

b) An application that runs on several nodes.

The usual trick is to take down part of your node cluster and upgrade that to the new version. It should be able to talk to the older nodes. Then bump the older nodes when the new version of Erlang has taken over.

Erlang does not provide this kind of upgrade for free. It does make it much less painful though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can not.

This is because applications compiled for the new version of the BEAM emulator (Erlang VM) would not run properly on older versions of the emulator.

Or in more details:

Upgrading an applications without stopping it can only be done using [release handler](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html). But release handler can only upgrade applications running in the VM, not the VM itself. You can still prepare a `relup` file but when [systools:make_relup/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/systools.html#make_relup-3) notices that the new [release](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html) uses a different version of the BEAM emulator it will add the instruction `restart_new_emulator (Low-Level)` to restart the node during the upgrade (see the description for `restart_new_emulator` on [the page I mentioned earlier](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html)).

What you could do, however, is upgrading the Erlang VM without interrupting the service (assuming your application provides some service to an external party). But that very much depends on the architecture of your application and has no generic answer.